# Create a new column in Pandas referencing a dict and other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing columns with 0's and 1's (A, B C). I also have a dictionary containing key, value pairs corresponding to the columns. What I'm trying to do is create a new column such as the final dataframe below. I know I can probably do this with map, but having a hard time remembering the correct syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [1, 0, 0], "B": [0, 0, 1],"C": [0, 1, 0]} )

    A   B   C
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   1
2   0   1   0

dict_ids = {'A':123, 'B':345, 'C':678}
{'A': 123, 'B': 345, 'C': 678}

df['ID'] = [123, 678, 345]
```

Final DF should look like this:

```
    A   B   C   ID
0   1   0   0   123
1   0   0   1   678
2   0   1   0   345
```

Comment: What happens if a row has more than one `1` value?

Answer (score 2):

We can try [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to convert the binary data to column values then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values using the dictionary:

```
df['ID'] = df.idxmax(axis=1).map(dict_ids)
```

*Note if there are no `1` values in a row it will use the value from `A` (the first column), if there are multiple `1` values in a row it will use the first column with value of `1`.

---

Assuming at most one `1` value per row we can take the [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) between the DataFrame and a Series created from the dictionary:

```
df['ID'] = df.dot(pd.Series(dict_ids))
```

*Note if there are no `1` values in a row the value will be `0`, if there are multiple `1` values the result will be the sum of the corresponding values for the `1` columns.

In this case, both options produce:

```
   A  B  C   ID
0  1  0  0  123
1  0  0  1  678
2  0  1  0  345
```

---

To handle more conditions we can [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by the column headers [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) on the DataFrame then [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) across rows into a collection:

```
# Modified Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 0, 0], "B": [1, 0, 0], "C": [0, 1, 0]})

dict_ids = {'A': 123, 'B': 345, 'C': 678}

df['ID'] = df.mul(df.columns).replace(dict_ids).aggregate(
    lambda x: x[x.ne('')].tolist(), axis=1
)
```

`df`:

```
   A  B  C          ID
0  1  1  0  [123, 345]
1  0  0  1       [678]
2  0  0  0          []
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
df['D']=(df.astype('boolean').agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1)# Get column values with one into rows, this comes as a list
         .str.join(',')#Strip of the column values the corner brackets
         .map(dict_ids)#Map the dict
        )
```